# mvc jquery tab display issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tabs, master-pages

In my view (that is being uploaded by a dialog) I have several tabs that are being displayed in order for that to happen I need to reference the jquery ui:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but due to incorporating this page withing a dialog I need to take this reference to my master page and use that in the contentplaceholders of my view, that is when i have the problem.

this is my code in the view:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">


     <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          $("#tabstest").tabs();
    });
    </script>

 </asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <h2>jQuery Tabs Example</h2>

  <div>
    <div id="tabstest">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("GetHomeTab");  %>            
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("GetProductTab");  %>         
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("GetContactUsTab");  %>           
    </div>
</div>    
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

if I remove the jquery UI reference to the master page I recieve this error " Object does not support method 'tabs'", but if I add the same reference to my view the tabs come up.

I will appreciate if anyone knows the reason of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the `<script src="...">` to your master page there shouldn't be any problem (I always do this). Check that you're putting it in the correct master page.

A way to test is would be the following:

- Run the page on your browser (there's a js error as you say)
- View its source code
- Look for the `<script src="..."` tag (the jquery ui inclusion).

I'm almost sure you don't have it.

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: Don't forget to include jquery.js, then jquery.ui, and then your scripts (to ensure you don't have a dependency problem)

Comment: thanks great point! but it did not solve the issue unfortunately, the source code that comes up on the dialog box is the source code of the parent page that I trigger the dialog box from

Comment: I would also use FireBug to see if the jquery stuff is double loading... i found i did that by accident doing almost exactly what Sue is doing... Each partial i was loading was also loading another jquery into the DOM... i resolved this by moving the script to the master.

Comment: Thank u,Thank u, Thank u Andy the partial views had references in them and that was the problem, can you share with me how you referenced the master page in those partialviews (ascx)?